# Force-Removing Windows Services

Tags: windows, installation, service

I am getting the following message while trying to remove a windows service with SC command?

```
C:\Users\chacha>sc delete service_name
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

I tried to change the properties of Service and retried to remove them but failed. Even I disabled the service and restarted the machine :(

Any idea on forcefully removing a service? What is the reason for this "Locking"?

Comment: Did you do that from an elevated command prompt?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try deleting it's entry from regedit at:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services**

Make sure you reboot afterwards.

Also:

- Try removing the service while in safe mode.

Comment: Regedit doesn't let me remove `TrustedInstaller` key.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Sysinternals Autoruns program to disable or delete the service.

Comment: Tried that... "access denied"

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need admin rights.

Before opening `cmd.exe` right click it and select "Run as administrator". Also you can hold `CONTROL+SHIFT` and press `ENTER` to open it with admin rights.

Comment: Even so, same error!

Comment: @marcolopes Then you are trying to remove a system service, or a service with more rights than your admin user.